# GLSL no rendering if gl_color is used

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, lwjgl

I am trying to render a texture in lwjgl using shaders. As soon as I use gl_Color in the vertex shader I got no ouput.

This is working:

```
#version 120

attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec2 fragmentCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    //gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    gl_FrontColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    fragmentCoord = (gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(texCoord, 0.0f, 1.0f)).xy;
}
```

This is not working:

```
#version 120

attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec2 fragmentCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    gl_FrontColor = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    fragmentCoord = (gl_TextureMatrix[0] * vec4(texCoord, 0.0f, 1.0f)).xy;
}
```

The fragment shader for both is:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;

varying vec2 fragmentCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, fragmentCoord) * gl_Color;
}
```

The same code works for a friend and I wonder why it doesnt for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only reason that would fail to work is if the vertex shader fails to compile. You are clearly writing the value of `gl_FrontColor` twice, so the actual value of `gl_Color` has nothing to do with the behavior at run-time. This is in all likelihood a compiler / linker error. Have you checked the logs thoroughly?

Answer (score 2):

The fragment shader should have this:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, fragmentCoord) * gl_FrontColor;
```

Since gl_FrontColor is an output of the vertex shader... gl_Color is not.

Comment: In the vertex shader gl_Color means the color attribute passed by the user and gl_FrontColor and gl_BackColor are the color outputs for the front and the backside of the drawn face. In the fragment shader gl_Color is the interpolated color that results for the fragment. Using gl_FrontColor in the fragment shader throws the following exception:
`error C5052: gl_FrontColor is not accessible in this profile`

Comment: **-1**: In the fragment shader, `gl_Color` has special meaning, it takes on the value of `gl_FrontColor` or `gl_BackColor` depending on which side of the polygon is being shaded. In oldschool GLSL you cannot even access `gl_FrontColor` or `gl_BackColor` explicitly in a fragment shader. It is generally better to avoid all this nonsense and write your own `varying` for front/back and then select the appropriate color to use based on the value of: `gl_FrontFacing` in the fragment shader stage.

Comment: @ClickerMonkey: Take a look at the [GLSL 1.2 spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf) pp. 54 - Built-in variables.